# JMeter fail tests if threshold exceeded

Tags: testing, jmeter, load, load-testing, threshold

I'm hoping that I can find help here because I didn't find anything on the internet. I have multiple JMeter plans and I want to fail the plan if a throughput threshold for a group of requests is exceeded. How can I get the real threshold value from JMeter and fail the test if it is exceeded. I need to do this per request, like the threshold value displayed in the Summary Report per each group of requets.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fail the "plan", you can fail only a sampler using [Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions)

The options are in:

1. Using JMeter [AutoStop Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/AutoStop/) stop the test if average response time exceeds threshold. After test finishes you can compare anticipated duration with real duration and if it less - state that test has failed somehow (i.e. return non-zero exit code
2. Using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper for your JMeter test you can use [Pass/Fail Criteria](http://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) subsystem to set the desired failure conditions. Taurus will automatically fail the test if the specified criteria is met.